# about button.addEventListener

Tags: javascript

If there are about 10 buttons and the buttons are numbered from 1 to 10, if button 1 is clicked, object 1 is created. If button 2 is clicked, object 2 is created and the remaining objects 1, 3 and 4 are deleted. I want to become In the present case, it is implemented by hard coding, but I want to keep this code neat and short. Help.

this is my code

```js
document.getElementById("leg_type2").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    Group1.children[1].visible = !Group1.children[1].visible;
    Group1.children[0].visible = false;
    Group1.children[2].visible = false;
    Group1.children[0].scale.set(0, 0, 0)
    Group1.children[1].scale.set(1, 1, 1)
    Group1.children[2].scale.set(0, 0, 0)
  });

document.getElementById("leg_type3").addEventListener("click",
  function() {
    Group1.children[2].visible = !Group1.children[2].visible;
    Group1.children[1].visible = false;
    Group1.children[0].visible = false;
    Group1.children[0].scale.set(0, 0, 0)
    Group1.children[1].scale.set(0, 0, 0)
    Group1.children[2].scale.set(1, 1, 1)
  });
```

Comment: Why do you tag the question with `nodejs`?  `addEventListener` indicates that it is client-side code running in the browser, how is the node engine related to that?

Comment: Should create a [mcve] of what you have (including the relevant html). Explain what part of the code creates a new object (in the shown code I don't see that any new object is created.) And you should show what you have tried to simplify your code and explain what part you had problems with. Also, the logic of the code within the click handler is not clear to me.

Comment: sorry. this is my first time this stack overflow.  i just use nodejs so i added that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that does this work for you:

```js
document.getElementById("leg_type2")
  .addEventListener("click", function () { toggle(2); });

document.getElementById("leg_type3")
  .addEventListener("click", function () { toggle(3); });

function toggle(index) {
  const { children } = Group1;

  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if (i !== index) {
      children[i].visible = false;
      children[i].scale.set(0,0,0);
    }
  }

  children[index].visible = true;
  children[index].scale.set(1, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: ohh it works well!! really nice!!! thank you so much.I've been thinking about this problem for 2 weeks, but it hasn't been solved
how do i think that!? i have no idea before..really